# Finding Probability with 'At-least One' in the statement

Tags: probability

A bag contains ten counters of which six are red and four are green. A counter is chosen at random; its colour is noted and it is replaced in the bag. A second is then chosen at random. Find the probability that at-least one is red.

With the help of answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2697163/finding-probability-with-10-counters), I have computed probability of having both green and this is 4/25.

And with the help of some website having similar question, I computed the probability of having at-least one red as

1 - (4/25) = 21/25.

And this is the right answer (checked from answers given at back of book).

I know that we have to subtract 4/25 but, I am unable to understand that why we have subtracted from 1.
Can anyone explain me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have only two options: in the end you have either zero reds, or you have at least one red.

More technically, if we let $R0$ be the event that you don't get any reds, and $R1^+$ the event that you get at least one red, then:

$$R0 + R1^+ = 1$$

because there are no other possible events: how can you *not* have zero reds, and *also not* have at least one red?! That's impossible. So, these events cover the whole space of possible outcomes, meaning that they must add up to $1$ or $100$%

Now, in this case to get zero reds is the same as getting two greens, so we know:

$$R0 = \frac{4}{25}$$

From which $R1^+$ readily follows:

$$R1^+ = 1- R0 = \frac{21}{25}$$

Comment: Thank you. I have understand it completely now.

Comment: @Student28 You're welcome! :)